# How to enable az security assessment on azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am attempting to use az security assessment as described here, [Azure Security Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/security/assessment?view=azure-cli-latest)

When I attempt to use it I see:

```
~$ az security assessment
az security: 'assessment' is not in the 'az security' command group. See 'az security --help'. If the command is from an extension, please make sure the corresponding extension is installed. To learn more about extensions, please visit https://docs.micro
soft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview
```

I have looked at that page, and while it tells me how to generally install extensions, nowhere can I find how to install whatever extension the assessment module might be in.

Has anyone used this and can point me in the right direction for getting it installed? I've looked at the list-available and nothing stands out as a security assessment.

Comment: My guess would be [Az.Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.security/).

Comment: Yes, but I don't need just basic az security, I need az security assessment for azure cli not powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run `az security assessment list` command and got the result like this:

[image]

[image]

I have below softwares installed:

1. Microsoft Azure CLI - 2.10.1
2. Microsoft Azure Powershell - 5.7.0.18831

As Ian Kemp mentioned above, you can also try installing `Az.Security`.

Comment: Thanks for that.

I am using az cli on WSL. I'm not looking to use powershell. However I am using:
```
  "azure-cli": "2.6.0",
```

I didn't see an update when I tried to update it, but i'll look deeper into that.

Comment: @JasonShive, this command works on cli also. I just prefer Powershell, that's why put up that snippet. Check my updated snippet.

Comment: Giving you the W on this because it was your version info that sealed the deal.
I upgraded and the command is now available.